# Trapezoid shaped div with background image that animates towards a rectangle when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I know what I am asking is somewhat weird so I will illustrate with images what I am aiming for:

1. First I want to have a trapezoid shaped div as below, instead of being blue I want it to have a bg image:

[image: Trapezoid div]

2. Then I want the trapezoid to animate towards this shape (rectangle) so it acts as a navbar, while keeping it's bg image (It doesn't have to resize or anything, but if there's a way to also blur the image it would be really nice).
   [image: Rectangle]

Is this possible at all? Any idea on how could I achieve this? I know JS so using JS to animate it would be no problem at all, the main problem I'm having is doing that trapezoid shape and being able to resize it to the rectangle while having a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clip-path can easily do this:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/800/800) top center/cover;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 70%);
  transition:1s;
}

html:hover .box {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
  height:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```